# CXF Redirect url to a static html page

Tags: spring, cxf

I have my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>static-resources-list</param-name>
            <param-value>/myfiles/(\w.*)+(.html|.js)</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring config:

```
<jaxrs:server id="services" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean class="com.abc.MyController"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

My restful resources are working good with URLs `http://localhost/appname/resource...`

Now I have a `src/main/webapp/myfiles/fileOne.html` in my source. 
I would like to use URL `http://localhost/appname/file` to redirect to fileOne.html. How do I do that??

**EDIT**:

I have added static-resources-list in above web.xml cxf configuration. I know that `http://localhost/appname/myfiles/fileOne.html` works but I want to use URL `http://localhost/appname/file` to serve the fileOne.html. How do I do that?

Comment: You might want to look into the "Redirecting requests and serving the static content" section of the CXF [Servlet Transport](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) documentation.  I have not used it personally, but it sounds like it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the documentation. But I didn't find a way to redirect a URL to other URL (not just prefixing as mentioned in the doc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution; Just in case anyone needs it.

redirects-list param at CXF servlet configuration didn't serve my purpose. So I added below servlet configuration in web.xml to redirect to my html page.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>swagger-ui</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/myfiles/fileOne.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>swagger-ui</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/file</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CXFServlet url mapping is the problem. You gave the mapping as /*. So all the requests, even the static resources are routed to CXFServlet. Try making the CXFServlet mapping to something else. It will work just fine. You don't need static-resources-list.

Because you gave the url mapping for CXFServlet as /*, every URL tries to find the response from CXFServlet which is giving the response as not found because it's jax-rs server doesn't know about the static resources.

Answer (score -1):

You can something like this in servlet tag:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>static-welcome-file</param-name>
   <param-value>/index.html</param-value>
</init-param>
```